# c2dm_on_rails gem - problem with migrations on Rails 3 ("no such file to load -- gdata (LoadError)")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gdata

When I try to do:

```
$ rails generate c2dm_migrations
```

I Get:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': no such file to load -- gdata (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
...
```

What's wrong?

PS: I made the same actions with apns_on_rails gem - it was ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's wrong?

It seems, that this gem works with Rails 2 only.
And *apns_on_rails* made another developers.